# Binding on Indexed properties UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I created UserControl.

```
public partial class Line : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    ObservableCollection < Point > points = new ObservableCollection< Point >();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SpeciesPropertyPoints = DependencyProperty.Register("Points", typeof(ObservableCollection<Point>),
                         typeof(Line), null);

    public ObservableCollection<PointPath> Points
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Point>)GetValue(SpeciesPropertyPoints); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SpeciesPropertyPoints, (ObservableCollection<Point>)value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Points");
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        var point = new Point(100, 50);
        points.Add(point);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)

    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}


public class Point: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   private double _x;
    public double X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set { _x = value; }
    }

    private double _y;
    public double Y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set { _y = value; }
    }

    public Point()
    {
        X = 0;
        Y = 0;
    }

    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
  Button Click="Button_Click" 
  TextBox x:Name="x" Width="20" Text="{Binding Points[0].X}" 
  TextBox x:Name="y" Width="20" Text="{Binding Points[0].Y}"
```

I want after clicking on button in TexBox with name "x" display Points[0].X (ie 100) and in TexBox with name "y" display Points[0].Y (ie 50). Please help me to understand.

Comment: Why your DP not format [Name]Property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change Text binding:

```
TextBox x:Name="x" Width="20" Text="{Binding Path=Points[0].X}" 
TextBox x:Name="y" Width="20" Text="{Binding Path=Points[0].Y}"
```

And your DP implementation is wrong,
should be like this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PointsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Points", typeof (ObservableCollection<Point>), typeof (Line), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<Point>)));

    public ObservableCollection<Point> Points
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Point>) GetValue(PointsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PointsProperty, value); }
    }
```

You should not write logic in DP setter, because its just CLR Property wrapper and it's not guaranteed that setter will be called in some cases!

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: @L.M.I. I tested code right now and it works. I cant see all your code, but index binding works

Comment: Thank you very much! I created a new project , everything works. Please tell me how create binding in two sides in this project, tried set Mode=TwoWay, but does not work.